# How to access data in html before BS Modal DOM load?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal, primeng

I have a  hyperlink, I open Modal on click of this click. It works fine. I'm using PrimeNG [organization chart](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/organizationchart) and assign the value to this organization chart by using `[value]="data1"`. I want to preselect a node when this modal renders to the end user. So I use `[(selection)]="data1[0].children[0]"`. But it gives the below error, but when I check `data1` in the console and in debugger mode its show data. Is there any way to set `data1` before modal loads. Or any other workaround?

> cannot read property children of undefined

So I think it's not getting data at the time of DOM loading. But again for the same reason `[value]="data1"` should also not work.

**First Page html**

```
<div class="row clearfix" [@routerTransition]>
    <div class="ui-grid-row"><a href="javascript:showcategorychart.show(record.id)">{{record.categoryName}}</a></div>
    <show-category-chart-modal #showcategorychart [categoryId]="categoryId"></show-category-chart-modal>
</div>
```

**First Page Typescript**

```
@ViewChild('showcategorychart') showcategorychart: CategoryChartData;

showCategoryChart(row): void {
    this.categoryId = row.id;
    this.showcategorychart.show();
};
```

**Modal HTML**

```
<div bsModal #showcategorychart="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="showcategorychart" aria-hidden="true" [config]="{backdrop: 'dynamic'}">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div #modalContent class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Category Hierarchy</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="content-section implementation">
                    <p-organizationChart [value]="data1" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedNode" (onNodeSelect)="onNodeSelect($event)"
                                         styleClass="company">
                        <ng-template let-node pTemplate="person">
                            <div class="node-header ui-corner-top">{{node.label}}</div>
                            <div class="node-content">
                                <img src="{{node.data.avatar}}" width="32">
                                <div>{{node.data.name}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </ng-template>
                        <ng-template let-node pTemplate="department">
                            {{node.label}}
                        </ng-template>
                    </p-organizationChart>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Modal Typescript**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'show-category-chart-modal',
    templateUrl: './categorydetails.html',
})
//@Directive({ selector: '[formGroupName]', providers: [formGroupNameProvider] })
export class CategoryChartData extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {
    data1: TreeNode[] = [];
    selectedNode: TreeNode;
    formGroup: any;
    @Input() parent;
    @ViewChild('showcategorychart') modal: ModalDirective;
    @ViewChild('modalContent') modalContent: ElementRef;
    @Input() categoryId: number;
    @Input() category: CategoryDto;
    @Output() modalSave: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    active: boolean = false;
    public categoryTemplate: TemplatesTypes[];
    public CategoryList: CategoryDto[] = [];
    form: FormGroup;
    name: string;

    constructor(
        injector: Injector,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private _categoryservice: CategoryServiceProxy,
        private _tokenService: TokenService,
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {
        super(injector);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    onSelectCategoryTemplate(templatesTypesId) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.categoryTemplate.length; i++) {
            if (this.categoryTemplate[i].id == templatesTypesId) {
            }
        }
        this.CategoryList = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            this.CategoryList.push(this.category);
        }
    }

    show(categoryid?: number): void {
        this.data1 = [];
        this.categoryId = categoryid;
        this.loadAll();
        this.modal.show();
    }

    close(): void {
        this.active = false;
        this.modal.hide();
    }

    loadAll() {
        this._categoryservice.getCategoryChartDataByCategoryID(this.categoryId).subscribe(
            (res) => {
                this.categoriestoTreeNodes(res);
                this.selectedNode = this.data1[0].children[0];
                console.log(this.selectedNode);
            }
        );
    }

    private categoriestoTreeNodes(categories: CategoryChartDto) {
        this.data1.push(this.categoriestoTreeNode(categories));
    }

    private categoriestoTreeNode(cont: CategoryChartDto): TreeNode {
        return {
            label: cont.label,
            type: cont.type,
            styleClass: cont.styleClass,
            expanded: cont.expanded,
            data: cont.data,
            children: cont.children,
            selectable: cont.selectable,
            parent: cont.selectedCategory
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to initialize `data1` ? `this.data1 = [{children:[]}]`

Comment: No not yet, I’ll try and update you

Comment: @Antikhippe Though I had already fixed the issue from the backend. I tried the fix provided by you, It works fine, Thanks a lot for your help. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Antikhippe Could you please help me in fixing this issue. Thanks in advance https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=55790?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think it's possible to solve your [problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50529763/how-to-create-multiple-root-in-organizationchart-primeng) with PrimeNG component...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent

> cannot read property children of undefined

when trying to access `data1[0].children[0]`, just initialize `data1` with empty data like that :

```
this.data1 = [{children:[]}]
```

Now, `data1[0]` equals `{children:[]}` and is not *undefined* anymore.

Answer (score 1):

**Backend solution**

I have solved the issue from backend application by setting `styleClass` property of `TreeNode`object from the backend for the particular node to `node-selected`.

**Frontend solution**

I have tried the solution by initializing `this.data1 = [{children:[]}]` provided by @Antikhippe also. Thanks for your answer. Its also working fine.

So if you want to fix this issue you have two choices now. You can do it from backend or frontend.